# Help me get vs help me to get

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Example sentences:

- I think that studying another day will help me to get a higher mark in the test
- I think that studying another week will help me to improve my qualities

This is how I would say these sentence, but now I am unsure whether this form is correct or not, because I see many people use the other form ("help me get").

Comment: This question has been asked [28 times](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/3578?sort=votes) before. Please search the site before asking. Thank you.

Comment: Some of the 28 times listed in the linked page are not instances of the same thing that is asked about here.